# PWA on Android - Pinned app: clicking back button makes app stop working

Tags: android, angular, progressive-web-apps

we developed a progressive web app with Angular. It is perfectly installable and executable on mobile devices.

Our requirement is that our customers can pin the PWA on their mobile Android tablets. That is, the user cannot exit the app until he or she enters the pin of the mobile device.

**Problem** 
If the user clicks the back button too often (in browsers this would cause the browser to show the default page as configured), the pinned PWA just shows a blank screen with the app logo. From there on, the user has no chance to do anything. In the end, our customer has to enter the pin and restart the app.

Is there any possibility to change this behavior as this is not happening with native android apps. We also tested the [web.dev](https://web.dev) PWA which has the same behavior, so its not just a problem of our code.

Best regards and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Eep, that is most certainly a bug in Chrome and Android. I've filed a bug [1174604](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1174604) with the team and will ask someone to look into it. I'd suggest staring the bug so that you get updates as it gets fixed.